# Are temporary values handled differently in a C++ coroutine?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, clang, c++-coroutine

I'm trying to use C++ coroutine and I'm running on mysterious use after free bug

Here is link to the complete code with all the coroutine boilerplate in godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/4shK19Eea

This are included bellow:

Compiler flags are: -ggdb3 -Og -std=c++20 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG -fsanitize=address

I tried g++-11.2 g++-12.0.1 and g++-12.1 but got the same result

However, clang++-14.0 is perfectly happy with this code

Any clues to what is happening?

```
using namespace std;

struct S {
 public:
  string s;

  int size() const { return s.size(); }
};

Task<int> str_size(const S v) {
  cout << v.s << endl;
  co_return v.size();
}

// This is fine

Task<int> test1() {
  auto s = S{.s = "foo"};
  auto p = co_await str_size(s);

  co_return p;
}

// This is fine too

Task<int> test2() {
  auto t =  str_size(S{.s = "foo"});
  auto p = co_await t;

  co_return p;
}

// This is not, address sanitizer claims this code causes a use after free

Task<int> test3() {
  auto p = co_await str_size(S{.s = "foo"});

  co_return p;
}
```

Comment: I assume you have already given https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/coroutines an in-depth read? I unfortunatly don't know enough about coroutines to be much of assistance, interesting topic though. (Also `using namespace std;`... eww...)

Comment: I did read it, but I didn’t find anything that would explain this behavior (i could have missed some subtle detail there, idk). Oh, and I don’t see the point of typing std:: a million times for a code snippet posted in stackoverflow. I could be convinced if there is evidence that it makes the code harder to understand.

Comment: Seems like a GCC bug, perhaps due to confused copy elision (although that ought to affect `test2` as well).

Comment: This is a known GCC bug https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=102217 Also related https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=98401 which in turn has links to several other related bug reports/